# Minimum requirements for creating DXF file with raster image entity

Tags: image, cad, dxf

I'm working on a small software. My software must be export a DXF file to work with Autocad.
On my DXF there area lines and a raster image. 
I'm reading the [DXF 2002 reference](http://www.autodesk.com/techpubs/autocad/dxf/dxf2002.pdf) (I have choose 2002 version for compatibily problems).
My application don't export a "perfect" dxf but a dxf with minimum requirements to use it with AutoCad.

If I try to export from my software only lines I can read the dxf file with Autocad (but also other CAD software).
My problem is the raster image. If export a dxf file with a raster image Autocad cannot read it I think because there are some error on my dxf.

This is [dxf file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19900180/working.dxf) with only a line (working on AutoCad).
This is [dxf file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19900180/notworking.dxf) with a line and a raster image (not working on AutoCad).

Somebody can help me to find DXF minimum requirements for raster image support.